# Using JavaScript only, how can I query a google sheet and assign the value of a single cell as a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

I am wanting to drive a web page using data from a few google sheets.

I’ve figure out how to query my sheet, but the data displays as a datatable and that’s not what I’m looking for. I’d like to be able to take the query cell value and insert it into HTML code. I will also use the value in another query in order to retrieve other information from a different google sheet.

I have two live pages:
http://www.bandstand.ca/widget

This page is a starter skeleton version of my project. I have “Day 5” statically coded and formatted for now but want to replace it with query data as per:
http://www.bandstand.ca/widget/sas.html

I had tried using getValue(0,0)  but must not have had something set right. I am totally new to using queries and have not been able to figure out if JavaScript can do anything with the content of the response. I tried hiding the div element that the query fills and just parsing content of the data table, but again, couldn’t figure out a workable solution. I’ve tried searching through the api documentation but I’m not finding anything that looks right either. Surely there’s a way to extract the data and use it within other html. I don’t particularly care if the code is clean (as I’m sure you can tell, I’ve hacked apart other peoples’ code to get the sas.html file down to where it’s at.) I just want something that works.

I’m a teacher and thought this would be an easy little project to build an in-class announcement page that I could have displayed all the time in my room and have it cycle through my schedule of classes via my easily updated google sheets. So far, not so easy! If anyone can help tweak my code to get what I’m asking, I’d sure be grateful!

Comment: If I understand you, you want on your page http://www.bandstand.ca/widget where   “Day 5” is written replace that with text that is written in your other page  http://www.bandstand.ca/widget/sas.html. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t want the table header or frame. Just the number that is saved in my google sheet cell. Once I get that working I will have other queries pulling other text cells for other places on the widget page.

Comment: "*I am wanting to drive a web page using data from a few google sheets.*" - why not use a real CMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function GetCurrentDate() {
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2;
 var day = currentTime.getDate();
 var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
 var currentDate = "'" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
 return currentDate;
}
 
function CreateUrl(key, gql) {
 var gq = 'SELECT '+ gql;
 var encodedgg = encodeURIComponent(gq);
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + key + '/gviz/tq?tq=' + encodedgg;
 return url;
}
 
function Request(url, responseFunction) {
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var response = this.responseText.substring(this.responseText.IndexOf("(")+1, this.responseText.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
   responseFunction(responseJSON);
  }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

function preview(elm, url) {
 fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(function(response) {
   var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
   var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
   elm.innerHTML = value;
  })
}

var gsKey = '1-dNm_AKv3Iiy-ggLjGJKHPwUqs379QJh0e4SzbEPcJQ';
var currentDate = GetCurrentDate();
var gql = "C WHERE A = DATE " + currentDate;
var url = CreateUrl(gsKey, gql);
var previewElement = document.getElementById('preview');
preview(previewElement, url);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Student Announcement System</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="preview">initial value</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is link to [jsbin snippet](https://jsbin.com/bukaxapuna/edit?html,js,output). (Inline stackoverflow snippet might not work because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).)

**EDIT** after [Greg Duguid's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127408/using-javascript-only-how-can-i-query-a-google-sheet-and-assign-the-value-of-a/53135760?noredirect=1#comment93168255_53135760):

There are three problems with your code:

1. Your scripts are not working at all. Try to run following snippet:

```html
<script>
  document.write("Text 1")
</script>

<script language = "text/javascript">
document.write("Text 2")
</script>


<script type = "text/javascript">
  document.write("Text 3")
</script>
```

When you run it you should get something like `Text 1 Text 3` and that is because `<script language = "text/javascript">` is wrong and won't work, `language` parameter is deprecated and you should use `type` instead. Also in HTML5 you can omit `type` parameter so it is best to use syntax like this `<script>document.write("Text")</script>`.

2. There is syntax error in function `preview`: last bracket `(` should be `)`.

```js
// OLD CODE
/*
function preview(elm, url) {
 fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(function(response) {
   var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
   var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
   //elm.innerHTML = value;
   DayNumber = value;
         }
       (      // ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
} 
*/



// NEW CODE
function preview(elm, url) {
 fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(function(response) {
   var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
   var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
   //elm.innerHTML = value;
   DayNumber = value;
         }
       )      // error WAS in this line
}
```

3. Code in line:

   ```
    <font size="+6" color="#FFFF00">Day <script>document.write(DayNumber);</script></font>
   ```

   When you call function `document.write(DayNumber)` variable `DayNumber` is equal to `""` because function `preview` is still not executed at that moment. Reason for this is that execution of function `preview` takes time. (Because you are retrieving data from sheet document, usually when you retrieve data from server or something similar that takes time.) Execution of code in javascript is asynchronous which means that javscript doesn't wait for function to finish with execution and goes on. Look at this example:

   ```
   function getData() {
       // some function that takes time to get data from server, ducument, or something else
       return data;
   }

   var data = getData();
   document.write(data);
   ```

   In first line function `getData()` is called, but data will be set to `undefined`  because program will not wait for function `getData()` to return its value. So function `document.write(data)` will not preview anything.

   (Also it is not good practice to use script tag inside another tag. So you should avoid putting script tag inside font tag like this: `<font size="+6" color="#FFFF00">Day <script>document.write(DayNumber);</script></font>`.)

   Solution for this problem is that you add `id` to you `font` tag and than change text in `font` tag in javascript inside function `preview`:

```js
function GetCurrentDate() {
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var month = currentTime.getMonth();
 var day = currentTime.getDate() + 1;
 var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
 var currentDate = "'" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
 return currentDate;
}
 
function CreateUrl(key, gql) {
 var gq = 'SELECT '+ gql;
 var encodedgg = encodeURIComponent(gq);
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + key + '/gviz/tq?tq=' + encodedgg;
 return url;
}
 
function Request(url, responseFunction) {
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var response = this.responseText.substring(this.responseText.IndexOf("(")+1, this.responseText.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
   responseFunction(responseJSON);
  }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

function preview(elm, url) {
 fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(function(response) {
   var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
   var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
   var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
   elm.innerHTML += " " + value;
         }
       )
}   

var gsKey = '1-dNm_AKv3Iiy-ggLjGJKHPwUqs379QJh0e4SzbEPcJQ';
var currentDate = GetCurrentDate();
var gql = "C WHERE A = DATE " + currentDate;
var url = CreateUrl(gsKey, gql);
var previewElement = document.getElementById('preview');
preview(previewElement, url);
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Student Announcement System</title>
 <body>
  <font size="+6" color="#FFFF00" id="preview">Day</font>
 </body>
</html>
```

This last code should be solution to your problem. Also here is [link to jsbin snippet](https://jsbin.com/rubihuneni/edit?html,js,output) (because stackoverflow snippet might not work when you run it).

**EDIT** after [second Greg Duguid's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127408/using-javascript-only-how-can-i-query-a-google-sheet-and-assign-the-value-of-a/53135760?noredirect=1#comment93189905_53135760):

Sorry it took little longer to answer. Problem is in line:

```
var previewElement = document.getElementById('preview');
```

When this line is executed `previewElement` is not found and it is set to `undefined`. This is because javascript code in script tag (`<script>...</script>`) is before body tag (`<body>...</body>`) so code is executed before elements in body are defined. So when your page is run, first javascript code is executed and then element `<font id="preview">Day</font>` is defined. There is simple solution for this: You need to put your script tag at the end of body like this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
 background-color: #003c66;
}
-->
</style>

  <title>Student Announcement System</title>
</head>

<body>
  <font size="+6" color="#FFFF00" id="preview">Day</font>
  
  
  <script>
  function GetCurrentDate() {
   var currentTime = new Date();
   var month = currentTime.getMonth()+1;
   var day = currentTime.getDate();
   var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
   var currentDate = "'" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
   return currentDate;
  }
   
  function CreateUrl(key, gql, sheet) {
   var gq = 'SELECT '+ gql;
   var encodedgg = encodeURIComponent(gq);
   var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + key + '/gviz/tq?tq=' + encodedgg + '&gid=' + sheet;
   return url;
  }
   
  function Request(url, responseFunction) {
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var response = this.responseText.substring(this.responseText.IndexOf("(")+1, this.responseText.lastIndexOf(")"));
     var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
     responseFunction(responseJSON);
    }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }

  function preview(elm, url) {
   fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(function(response) {
     var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
     var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
     var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
     elm.innerHTML += " " + value;
        }
      )
  }   

  var gsKey = '1-dNm_AKv3Iiy-ggLjGJKHPwUqs379QJh0e4SzbEPcJQ';
  var gsSheet='349215948';
  var currentDate = GetCurrentDate();
  var gql = "C WHERE A = DATE " + currentDate;
  var url = CreateUrl(gsKey, gql, gsSheet);
  var previewElement = document.getElementById('preview');
  preview(previewElement, url);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

And again here is [jsbin snippet](https://jsbin.com/fowitomaka/edit?html,js,output) which should work.

**EDIT** after [this Greg Duguid's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127408/using-javascript-only-how-can-i-query-a-google-sheet-and-assign-the-value-of-a/53135760?noredirect=1#comment93595500_53135760):

The problem is in your query:

```
var PERIODgql = "C WHERE A = " + value + " AND B = " + CurrentPeriod;
```

`CurrentPeriod` is string so you need to add single quotes around it like this:

```
var PERIODgql = "C WHERE A = " + value + " AND B = '" + CurrentPeriod + "'";
```

When it is created, `PERIODgql` will be something like:

```
"C WHERE A = 1 AND B = 'P5'"
```

These queries are similar to SQL queries (which are used to get data form SQL database), you can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Setting_the_Query_in_the_Data_Source_URL#where).

Also i noticed your function `FindCurrentPeriod`:

```
function FindCurrentPeriod() {
    var CurrentPeriod;
    var CurrentDate = new Date();

    //////////////////////////////
    //FOR TESTING VARIOUS TIMES
    CurrentDate.setHours(14);
    CurrentDate.setMinutes(0);
    //////////////////////////////


    var CurrentHour = CurrentDate.getHours();
    var CurrentMinute = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
    if (CurrentHour < 8) {
        CurrentPeriod = "Before School";
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 8) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 40) {
            CurrentPeriod = "Before School";
        } else {
            CurrentPeriod = "P1";
        }
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 9) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 40) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P1";
        } else {
            if (CurrentMinute < 45) {
                CurrentPeriod = "B12";
            } else {
                CurrentPeriod = "P2";
            }
        }
    }
    if (CurrentHour == 10) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 37) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P2";
        } else {
            if (CurrentMinute < 47) {
                CurrentPeriod = "B23";
            } else {
                CurrentPeriod = "P3";
            }
        }
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 11) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 39) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P3";
        } else {
            if (CurrentMinute < 44) {
                CurrentPeriod = "B34";
            } else {
                CurrentPeriod = "P4";
            }
        }
    }
    if (CurrentHour == 12) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 36) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P4";
        } else {
            CurrentPeriod = "Lunch";
        }
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 13) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 13) {
            CurrentPeriod = "Lunch";
        } else {
            CurrentPeriod = "P5";
        }
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 14) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 5) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P5";
        } else {
            if (CurrentMinute < 10) {
                CurrentPeriod = "B56";
            } else {
                CurrentPeriod = "P6";
            }
        }
    }

    if (CurrentHour == 15) {
        if (CurrentMinute < 2) {
            CurrentPeriod = "P6";
        } else {
            CurrentPeriod = "After School";
        }
    } else {
        CurrentPeriod = "After School";
    }
    return CurrentPeriod;

}
```

While this is working, it is not really easy to read and there is some repeating conditions so if need to change your code later, that will be harder to do. So I would suggest using a function to help you compare time (in hours and minutes). You can add just short function like this:

```
function time(hours, minutes) {
    return hours*60 + minutes;
}
```

Now you can compare times 10:50 and 11:25 like this:

```
if (time(10,50) < time(11,25)) {
    //part when you do what you want if condition is ture
}
```

So you can write your function `FindCurrentPeriod` like this:

```
function FindCurrentPeriod() {
    var CurrentPeriod;
    var CurrentDate = new Date();

    //////////////////////////////
    //FOR TESTING VARIOUS TIMES
    CurrentDate.setHours(14);
    CurrentDate.setMinutes(0);
    //////////////////////////////

    var CurrentHour = CurrentDate.getHours();
    var CurrentMinute = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
    var cirrentTime = time(CurrentHour, CurrentMinute);

    if (cirrentTime < time(8, 40)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "Before School";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(9, 40)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P1";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(9, 45)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "B12";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(10, 37)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P2";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(10, 47)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "B23";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(11, 39)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P3";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(11, 44)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P3";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(12, 36)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P4";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(13, 13)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "Lunch";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(14, 5)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P5";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(14, 10)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "B56";
    }
    else if (cirrentTime < time(15, 2)) {
        CurrentPeriod = "P6";
    }
    else {
        CurrentPeriod = "After School";
    }


    return CurrentPeriod;

}
```

This is shorter and also easier to read and change if needed.

Here is whole code in stackoverflow snippet (again I'll add jsbin snippet below, because inline stackoverflow snippet might not work because of CORS rules):

```js
function preview2(elm, url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.text())
        .then(function(response) {
            var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
            var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
            elm.innerHTML = value;
        })
}

function GetCurrentDate() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var currentDate = "'" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
    return currentDate;
}

function CreateUrl(key, gql, sheet) {
    var gq = 'SELECT ' + gql;
    var encodedgg = encodeURIComponent(gq);
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + key + '/gviz/tq?tq=' + encodedgg + '&gid=' + sheet;
    return url;
}

function time(hours, minutes) {
 return hours*60 + minutes;
}


function FindCurrentPeriod() {
    var CurrentPeriod;
    var CurrentDate = new Date();

    //////////////////////////////
    //FOR TESTING VARIOUS TIMES
    CurrentDate.setHours(14);
    CurrentDate.setMinutes(0);
    //////////////////////////////


    var CurrentHour = CurrentDate.getHours();
    var CurrentMinute = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
 var cirrentTime = time(CurrentHour, CurrentMinute);
 
 if (cirrentTime < time(8, 40)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "Before School";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(9, 40)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P1";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(9, 45)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "B12";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(10, 37)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P2";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(10, 47)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "B23";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(11, 39)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P3";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(11, 44)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P3";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(12, 36)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P4";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(13, 13)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "Lunch";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(14, 5)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P5";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(14, 10)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "B56";
 }
 else if (cirrentTime < time(15, 2)) {
  CurrentPeriod = "P6";
 }
 else {
  CurrentPeriod = "After School";
 }
 
    return CurrentPeriod;
}

function preview1(elm, url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.text())
        .then(function(response) {
            var responseText = response.substring(response.indexOf("(") + 1, response.lastIndexOf(")"));
            var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var value = response['table']['rows'][0]['c'][0]['v'];
            elm.innerHTML += " " + value;

            var CurrentPeriod = FindCurrentPeriod();
            var PERIODgsSheet = '618896702';
            var PERIODgql = "C WHERE A = " + value + " AND B = '" + CurrentPeriod + "'";
            var PeriodURL = CreateUrl(gsKey, PERIODgql, PERIODgsSheet);
            var periodElement = document.getElementById('period1');
            preview2(periodElement, PeriodURL);


        })

}




var gsKey = '1-dNm_AKv3Iiy-ggLjGJKHPwUqs379QJh0e4SzbEPcJQ';

var DAYgsSheet = '349215948';
var currentDate = GetCurrentDate();
var DAYgql = "C WHERE A = DATE " + currentDate;
var DayURL = CreateUrl(gsKey, DAYgql, DAYgsSheet);
var previewElement = document.getElementById('preview');
preview1(previewElement, DayURL);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" />
      <title>Student Announcement System</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         <!--
            body {
             background-color: #003c66;
            }
            -->
      </style>
      <!-- CSS Code -->
      <style type="text/css" scoped>
         .GeneratedMarquee {
         font-family:'Arial Black', sans-serif;
         font-size:8em;
         font-weight:bold;
         line-height:2em;
         text-align:left;
         color:#ffff00;
         background-color:#003c66;
         padding:40pt;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width=100%>
         <tr>
            <td width=240px>
               <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:240px;height:80px;"src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=004&timezone=MST&color=white&size=240&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2018,1,1,0,0,0&Color=white"></iframe>
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
               <center>
                  <font size="80px" color="#FFFF00" id="preview">DAY </font>
               </center>
            </td>
            <td width=100%>
               <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/53d54n113d49/edmonton/" data-label_1="EDMONTON" data-font="Helvetica" data-icons="Climacons Animated" data-days="7" data-theme="original" data-basecolor="#003c66" ></a>
               <script>
                  !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
               </script>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <font color="FFFFFF", size="+6">
         <script language=javascript>
            var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
            var today  = new Date();
            
            document.write(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)); // Saturday, September 17, 2016
            formattedDate = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
            
         </script>
      </font>
      <br><font size="80px" color="#FFFF00" id="period1">Class:</font>
      <script src="sas.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is [jsbin snippet](https://jsbin.com/dumijonuha/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: It seems like this is going to work, but I have an issue somewhere in my code that I am hoping you can spot. I have reworked it slightly in hopes of getting it right where I want it, but the cell value isn't writing to my doc like it does in the jsbin snippet. The new live page is at http://www.bandstand.ca/widget/new_sas.html.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: IT works beautifully in the jsbin snippet, but for the life of me, I can not get it to work live. Here is the updated live version:  http://bandstand.ca/widget/newest_sas.html   I am extremely grateful for your assistance. I love that you are teaching me along the way. Thank you!

Comment: I am getting really excited about the progress here. As I indicated in my original post, I need to be able to use the query response as a variable value to do some calculations, in order to make a further query on another sheet. I've reworked my files a little, and now have two queries running. For the second query I need the value from the first.

Comment: I've been trying to test the variables using alert functions, but am getting nowhere. I've declared global variables to hold the query results, and I can assign the results to the variables within the preview functions. If I run an alert within the preview function it works, but when I move the alert call to outside of the function, the values disappear. I must be missing a detail with variable scope. The current files are at bandstand.ca/widget/index.html and bandstand.ca/widget/sas.js

Comment: I tried to run website, and it work for me. Regarding your tries to alert variables, that won't work. Not because of variable scope, but because it can't work. When you define variables `DayNumber`, `PeriodClass`, they are set to `undefined`. And than when you call function `alert("Day " + DayNumber + ", " + PeriodClass)` you get `Day undefined, undefined` and that is because `DayNumber` and `PeriodClass` are still `undefined` and function `preview1` and `preview2` still haven't finished with execution.

Comment: So I don't know what you are trying to do but you can use `DayNumber` and `PeriodClass` only inside `preview1` and `preview2` functions. You can tell me why you think that you need to use `preview1` and `preview2`outside preview functions and I'll try to help you to find a way to do that inside preview functions.

Comment: Using the day number along with the current time, I want to run a query on a different spreadsheet that will then tell me what class is currently in session. Based on that class it will run another 2 queries to look up relevant announcements for the class. I know the chain reaction of queries will be slow, but I’m not terribly worried about load time. Would inserting a timing loop to slow down the JavaScript be enough to allow the queries to finish? I assume there isn’t a “wait until a variable becomes defined” function.

Comment: Ok, I think I might be starting to understand what I need to do. Please confirm for me...

Comment: I should use the current preview1 function as originally conceived. Within the preview1 function use the value variable to call another function which then runs another query with the time and passed variable.  From there call another function that uses the passed ClassName variable to query the announcements. I should be able to output the various variable values as html text, as done with the initial preview function, as needed. Am I now thinking correctly? (Thanks again for all this help and thank you for your patience! Hopefully I’m on the right track and I can put this to bed soon!)

Comment: Yes, that should work. When you implement this and you add this to your webpage just comment here and I will check your code.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I had the second query ready to fire and output to html, but something is stopping it now that I have implemented actual variables into the query URL. The files are at http://bandstand.ca/widget/index.html and http://bandstand.ca/widget.sas.js

Comment: Have you tried what I have suggested in my last edit?

Comment: Sorry,  no. I didn’t see the edit as I kept scrolling to the bottom to see if anything was new there. Oops! Thanks, I will look at it later this week and see what I can make of it.